# What's the meaning of \* and \*\* in a function definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

example:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x, y, s=None, c=None, marker=None,
                          cmap=None, norm=None, vmin=None, vmax=None,
                          alpha=None, linewidths=None,
                          verts=<deprecated parameter>,
                          edgecolors=None,
                          \*, plotnonfinite=False, data=None, \*\*kwargs)
```

I know that `*` is used when you are passing a list, and `**` is used for a dictionary. I don't get the use of `\`.

Comment: The backslashes look like someone tried to use this function call as part of some string where they had to escape the `*` character. Otherwise they don’t seem to make sense to me. But it’s hard to tell without more context.

Comment: That's a syntax error, whether its a function definition or function call.

Comment: The previous duplicate was not correct; this is not about positional-only or keyword-only arguments.

Comment: This looks like some sort of pseudo-code for documentation; no idea why the `*` are escaped.

Comment: Possibly the code is intended to be used in a Markdown document (where you'd have to escape the `*` characters to prevent them from being interpreted as italics or boldface).